# Solve a simple complex partial differential equation

Tags: complex-analysis, complex-numbers, partial-derivative, partial-differential-equations

I am looking at the following equation:

$$\partial_z \left\lbrace (1-z)^2 f (z,\bar{z}) \right\rbrace = 0, \tag{1}$$

with $z = x+ i y$ and $\bar{z} = x - i y$. Can I directly conclude without any caveat that

$$f(z,\bar{z}) = \frac{c(\bar{z})}{(1-z)^2}, \tag{2}$$

as in the real case?

Comment: "as in the real case" ??

Comment: @YvesDaoust Like in the case where $z$ is real and independent of $\bar{z}$. Does that clear it up?

Comment: Real $z$ independent of $\bar z$. Does not that mean $x$ independent of $x$ ?

Comment: @YvesDaoust No, that means that the bar labeling loses its meaning of complex conjugate and instead $\bar{z}$ is a variable independent of $z$. You can name them $x$ and $y$ if you like. But really, isn't eq. $(2)$ self-explanatory?

Comment: Yes, but $(1)$ is unclear.

Answer (score 0):

I think that I could solve it myself using Wirtinger derivatives. The complex derivative is defined as:

$$\partial_z := \frac{1}{2} \left(\partial_x - i \partial_z \right) \tag{3}$$

Hence my partial differential equation becomes:

$$\partial_x \left\lbrace (1-x-iy)^2 f(x,y) \right\rbrace = i\partial_y \left\lbrace (1-x-iy)^2 f(x,y) \right\rbrace \tag{4}$$

where by abuse of notation I wrote $f(x,y)$ instead of $f(z,\bar{z})$. The meaning should be clear though. This is now a real PDE, and the solution is:

$$f(x,y) = \frac{c(x-iy)}{(1-x-iy)^2} \tag{5}$$

which is precisely $(2)$. Actually, it seems that the Wirtinger derivative was *defined* such that it has the behavior of ordinary derivatives.

Comment: In your question, $\partial_z$ is not defined. So you are free to assign it any meaning *after the fact*.